# How do I enter a degree symbol – ° – on an iPhone or iPad?

Tags: ios, text-input, unicode

Let's say I'm working on my pork belly recipe [I'm not – [there's only one you'll ever need](http://luckypeach.com/recipes/momofuku-pork-belly/)] and I want to record a temperature. I don't want to write out "500 degrees" I want to write "500°". How do I do this?

Comment: Although you found out the answer yourself, I would like to add that googling the character (by name) you want in the browser and then copy pasting the search result also comes in handy :)

Comment: @user3098466 And I've got [a more efficient take](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249471/180636) on your method....

Comment: Let me know if my solution works :). I think you'll enjoy it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've looked around for this several times but today I just found its hiding spot – the <kbd>0</kbd> key! Just hold <kbd>0</kbd> until the alternate characters are shown. In the case of <kbd>0</kbd>, the only alternate character is '°'.

Comment: That's not a degree, Degree: °, Not Degree: º. Side by side: °º. That's to the power of 0.

Comment: @SBoss Aaargh! You're right! But I guess it's close enough – just a matter of degrees (of eccentricity of the rendered ellipse)!

Comment: @SBoss I think my answer *does* result in a degree symbol; here it is – °. I think I just assumed that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> on my Mac would be the same as the sole extended character for *0* on my iPhone.

Comment: Seems like you're right! I didn't bother to check the created symbol on the phone, since the one in the answer was incorrect :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Head over to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol) and copy the ° symbol to your clipboard from the first sentence of the page.
2. [Go to the **Text Replacement** page in Settings.](http://www.imore.com/how-to-setup-text-keyboard-shortcuts-iphone-ipad-ios)
3. In the phrase field, paste your real degree symbol that you copied from Wikipedia.
4. In the shortcut field, type any shortcut phrase, like maybe the word `degree`)
5. Now when you type your shortcut, the real degree symbol (°) will appear automagically.

Comment: @KennyEvitt So now the challenge of deciding which one you're going to accept (no hard feelings if it's not mine) !

Comment: On my iPhone, currently running iOS 9.3.2, the relevant settings seem to be named "Text Replacement"; I couldn't find any 'shortcuts' under the keyboard settings.

Comment: Your answer covers a great feature to know about, and it certainly works, but it turned out that my answer is just a little bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you're using an external Bluetooth keyboard with your hardware keyboard set to US, type Option - Shift - 8.